# How to Debug Java EE Web application When it's Live

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I want to debug a java EE web application that run on Apache Tomcat. Is there any way to debug the application without stoping the server.

Comment: I don't see how live debugging a server would be any better than restarting it. Both can cause issues in live operation.

Answer (score 0):

you can't. The server have to be started in debug mode.

I invite you to read the wiki: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing

If you don't want to restart your live tomcat.

Create a new server (configured in debug mode), then copy you application on it.
Debug on this server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use remote debugging, but you'll need your server (once) to be started with the correct arguments for that. For instance, since you are using Tomcat, you can add these arguments in catalina.sh:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

Then you can attach your debugger to REMOTE_IP:8000 and start debugging.

Always take into account that you are working in a production environment, so be careful with this.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to start Tomcat with remote debugging enabled.

The easy way to do this is to use the options `jpda start` if you start tomcat using the `catalina.sh` or `catalina.bat` shell script.

If you are starting Tomcat using your IDE or something, then you must add the following options to the JVM that runs Tomcat:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

After you do that, then you need to configure your IDE to connect to the remote debugging port.

Check this [Tomcat FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing#Q1) for more information.